# Ubuntu Server Installation "Signal Out of Range"

Tags: 14.04, server, monitor

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 server ISO on my server successfully, but when starting after the installation, I keep getting "Signal out of range", I have read multiple things online to go into the terminal where I can't really do anything.

I have also tried Ubuntu server 14.04.5 and the same issue.

Anyone with anything at all I would appreciate.

HARDWARE: Hp DL140 G2, I know it's old but I just got it in the trash at Columbia university.

Comment: What signal is this about? Wifi ??  Please add a screenprint

Comment: @WillemK it sounds like it's the monitor is saying signal out of range, like it can't display the resolution. Does this sound right? As in you installed it just fine but once it reboots you get no image ?

Comment: Ah, I get it. At which point do you get this message? During grub or while Ubuntu is starting? What are the resolutions the attached monitor supports? What was the resolution while you were running the Live USB?   Have a look at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu

Comment: @WillemK Yes, after I installed Ubuntu, I get this error, as for a screenshot, the problem looks exactly like this. https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Qv-wh_mHrI4/VtgcnFF1cUI/AAAAAAAABUE/GhU_sRO8FtI/s1600/20141222_617d948f1231badff812Pxz6HGOoDISS.jpg

Comment: I get this problem once I start and boot into Ubuntu, the resolution during installation was my native monitor resolution 1920x1080 at 60hz. The problem is running at an unknown resolution at H = 47.0Khz V = 87Hz.

Comment: @WillemK  My BIOS version is PhoenixBIOS V1.17 but I don't know if I can change the resolution in there, the installation changed the Date in the BIOS so I believe I can also change the resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem, I took the HDD out of my server and booted it on my PC. From there I was able to edit the Grub to my resolution.